# Does deflate compress tightly interleaved compressible and non-compressible data well?

Tags: compression, deflate

Let's say I have a repeatable pattern, like random data of 4 random bytes, 4 predictable bytes, 4 new random bytes, same 4 predictable bytes, and so on. Is this something deflate can compress well?

Are 4 bytes too short for it to compress well?
Does deflate have any built-in support for interleaved compressible/non-compressible data like this?
Does any other common compression format handle this pattern better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to define "well", but yes, deflate can and  will take advantage of repeating strings as short as three bytes.

There's nothing like just trying it. I generated 100,000 sets of four random bytes followed by four zeros, so 800,000 bytes total. gzip compressed it to about 500,000 bytes. That's not bad, as it certainly couldn't do better than 400,000, which is the size of the random data.

Comment: What if you have only 1 random byte / 1 predictable byte / 1 random byte .... and so on? In that case it seems like the algorithm would fail. But if you were to reshape the string into all odd bytes followed by all even bytes, it could compress it almost perfectly. Is that beyond the capability of deflate?

Comment: That is not something that deflate could detect or take advantage of. It would require the pre-processing you suggest. In fact taking the transpose of a table is a common way to improve compression, by turning columns with correlated values into rows.